# Should PnP or SCOM replace the snapin for SharePoint 2016 onprem

Tags: 2016, pnp-powershell, scom

We currently have SharePoint 2013 and are now moving to SharePoint 2016. As part of this we are looking whether or not to retire the use of the PowerShell snapin - Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell in favor of PnP. A number of posts have mentioned falling back to using the SCOM (via Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll).

Is PnP mature enough to replace the SharePoint snapin for SharePoint 2016 onprem?
If the SharePoint snapin is no longer viable, is falling back to using the SCOM module worth considering for SharePoint 2016 and onwards?
Is PnP or SCOM a better option for PowerShell scripts and admin management from the command line for SharePoint 2016?

Most of our administration CLi work is coded into functions using the Snapin which worked well for SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an on-prem farm, it won't be possible to 'retire' the use of the SharePoint snapin due to functions that are simply not available via CSOM to manage a farm.

I think it is a great idea to learn the PnP module and CSOM as it will provide you a better understanding of the capabilities available in SPO should you migrate, but I wouldn't put a lot of effort into it unless the module is more convenient and easier to work with for the task you're performing.

Comment: It was more that there are issues with using the snapin on SharePoint 2016. Sometimes it fails to load, and other times shows an error about already being loaded, which is a known problem with snapins that has become significant enough to look for alternatives. It looks like we'll just need to work around the snapin loading issues and hope for the best.

Comment: Not sure about your failing to load scenarios, but you should use `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0` to prevent the already loaded messages.